# Consistent url routing on client side React app served from Express

Tags: javascript, cookies, express, reactjs, react-router

I am currently using Express to load a one page client side app in React.js and react-router.

It is structured such that I have /about and /contact as standard jade views, but /ui as the actual react app. Any subsequent navigation beyond /ui such as ui/dashboard is handled by react-router. This means that if I need to visit www.foobar.com/ui/dashboard, I would need to hit my route for ui*, grab the url past ui/ (dashboard in this case) and pass that to react router (via variable in the jade view which is the react app's entry point) which then loads this route from a react component. I would like to make this approach work as this enables users to save urls for the react app. Trouble is I can't figure out how this could work as:

- I cannot pass variables with express router redirects
- I need to load the react app without anything beyond /ui as otherwise react router will append its routing urls in front of it ruining the point in this approach
- I cannot store the initial request url in a cookie and then redirect as I need to send a response in order to set a cookie
- I cannot satisfactorily modify the url via client side js

Code:

```
//Example 1
router.get('/ui*', requireLogin, function(req, res){
    res.render('./app/index', {initURL: req.path); //Doesnt work as everything past ui/ is still present when react-router does its thing
}); 

//Example 2
router.get('/ui', requireLogin, function(req, res){
    res.render('./app/index', {initURL: req.path); //Doesnt work as no way of accessing the initial requests url when redirecting
});

router.get('/ui*', requireLogin, function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/ui'); //Cant pass additional parameters here
});
```

Comment: The first example seems most reasonable. And I don’t really understand the comment "Doesnt work as everything past ui/ is still present when react-router does its thing" – isn’t this exactly what you want? If not – then try using `History.replaceState` before react router "does it’s thing". Although, it seems rather crazy to pass the path as a variable, remove it from the address bar and then add it again.

Comment: @David I was able to resolve the issue using the history module from npm and using History.replaceState, cheers! I was using it incorrectly before, and was confusing myself by not changing the default routing system of react-router so I was getting the #/?_k=mc0v9g at the end of my url's which didn't help. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express')
var React = require('react')
var Router = require('react-router')

var routes = require('./routes')

var app = express()

app.use('/ui', requireLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  // store initially requested url as a query parameter
  // e.g. /ui/dashboard would become /ui?redirect=dashboard
  // if the user is not logged in 
  var params = req.query;
  // params.redirect === 'dashboard'
  // Now you can check if there is a redirect and use it in your initial route
  var router = Router.create({location: req.url, routes: routes})
  router.run(function(Handler, state) {
    var html = React.renderToString(<Handler/>, {initalState: params.redirect})
    return res.render('react_page', {html: html})
  })
})
```

Does this get you on the right track?

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion - I went with another approach that worked for me but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to distinguish your client side routing and your server side routing.

You will need a server side routing:

- the client needs to load the static content (*.html, *.js, *.css)
- the client needs to authenticate, and load the data he needs (/api/...)

You will also need a client side routing framework (like ui.router for angular.js):

- you will split your client application logically in different routes that the browser (user) can remember, like /, /dashboard, /...

Regards, Remy

Comment: This does not really solve my problem as I have already created the routing to load assets to the client - my issue lies in forwarding routes to react-router within the client such that accessing a url in the client app results in the server loading the client app with the correct view displayed.